# How to determine and derive the protonation state of a functional group based on its pKa?

Tags: acid-base, ph

In our biochemistry class we were introduced to a rule of thumb, which goes something like this:

"If the pH of a solution is one or more units below the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ of a group, then said group is protonated and if it is one or more unit above, then the group is de-protonated"

However, we weren't provided with a mathematical derivation of this fact. 
I attempted one by myself using:

$$\ce{HA + H2O <=> A- + H3O+}$$
thus, $$\ce{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log\frac{\ce{A-}}{\ce{HA}}$$
or, $$\ce{pH} = \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log\frac{1-\alpha}{\alpha}$$

and then define $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ as the point where ${\alpha=0.5}$ i.e proton occupancy is 50%

$$\alpha(\ce{pH}) = \frac{1}{1+\exp\left\{-\ln10(\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}-\ce{pH})\right\}}$$

where $\alpha$:= degree of proton occupancy.

By looking at this function, I can sort of get that if pH goes up, $\alpha$ goes down i.e case of protonation, and if pH goes down  $\alpha$ goes up i.e case of deprotonation.

This seems a little bit "back of the envelope" to me. Is this sufficient, or am I missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track.  The Henderson-Hasselbalch equation is where this *rule of thumb* comes from; the key thing to remember is that, in biochemistry, your $\mathrm{pH}$ is fixed by the environment (there's always something acting as a buffer).  This is in contrast with typical H.H. problems in general chemistry where the amount of molecule and its $K_\mathrm{a}$ is changing the $\mathrm{pH}$ of the solution.

Anyhow, given that $\mathrm{pH}$ and $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ are fixed values, we're free to simply compare the ratio of $[\ce{A-}]$ and $[\ce{HA}]$:

\begin{align}
\mathrm{pH} &= \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} + \log\frac{[\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]}\\
\log\frac{[\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]} &= \mathrm{pH} - \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}\\
\frac{[\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]} &= 10^{\mathrm{pH} - \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}}\\
\end{align}

If $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = \mathrm{pH} + 1$ then we have $\frac{[\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]} = 10^{-1}$.  In other words, we have 10 times as much $\ce{HA}$ as we have $\ce{A-}$ (i.e., we have $\approx91\%\ \ce{HA}$) as we should expect for something that is mildly basic.

If $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = \mathrm{pH} - 1$ then we have $\frac{[\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]} = 10^{1}$.  In other words, we have 10 times as much $\ce{A-}$ as we have $\ce{HA}$ (i.e., we have $\approx91\%\ \ce{A-}$) as we should expect for something that is mildly acidic.

Clearly, if the $\mathrm{pH}$ differs from the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ by only 1 $\mathrm{pH}$ unit, we don't really have a *completely* protonated or deprotonated molecules, but it's certainly *mostly* protonated or deprotonated.  As the $\mathrm{pH}$ and $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ get further apart, then we continue to change this ratio by orders of magnitude.

Let's look at a concrete example.  Physiological $\mathrm{pH}$ is 7.4 and the side chain of aspartic acid has a carboxylic acid group with a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} = 3.9$, so we predict

$$\frac{[\ce{RCOO^-}]}{[\ce{RCOOH}]} = 10^{7.4 - 3.9} = 10^{3.5} = 3200$$

In other words, we still have some protonated sidechain, but we have >3000 times more deprotonated sidechain than protonated sidechain (did you notice that? the difference was >3 so we have >1000 difference in concentration ratio).  For all practical purposes, the aspartic acid side chain is "completely deprotonated" at physiological $\mathrm{pH}$.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be formatted using $\LaTeX$ syntax. I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). (Please do not use markup in the title field, see [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/149/4945) for details.)